# increasing value with condition on oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, lag

How to add an increment value (not summarize) with some condition on another column?

I'm using Oracle-like DBMS, named Tibero, for simple example i want to produce this data

[image: GRP_NO is TARGET_GROUPING]

```
ROWNUM GRP_STRT GRP_NO SLBY
1      1        1      1
2      1        1      1
3      1        1      1
4      1        1      1
5      1        1      1
6      1        2      0
7      1        2      0
8      1        3      1
9      1        3      1
10     1        3      1
11     1        4      0
12     1        5      1
```

Column SLBY is for Buy/Sell code (0=Buy, 1=Sell) then every changing type of transaction, column GRP_NO increasing (but it's not grouping by SLBY column)

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN ROWNUM = 1 THEN GRP_NO
    WHEN ROWNUM <> 1 AND SLBY = LAG(SLBY,1) over (ORDER BY ROWNUM) THEN LAG(GRP_STRT,1) over (ORDER BY ROWNUM) - 1
    WHEN ROWNUM <> 1 AND SLBY_DSTN_CD <> LAG(SLBY_DSTN_CD,1) over (ORDER BY ROWNUM) THEN LAG(GRP_STRT,1) over (ORDER BY ROWNUM) + 1
        END TARGET_GROUPING
        , A.* 
FROM SOME_TABLE
```

I tried with that query but instead of getting what i want like in the picture above, I produced a GRP_NO like 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 (first change SLBY only)

Apologies for my bad english and bad explanation, I'll explain more if need further information, thanks for your help!

Comment: Expected output and actual output would be helpful

Comment: expected output like on the attached picture, actual output below the query

Comment: No Images please. I am not even able to open the image. Can you please paste the expected output in your question?

Comment: You have the rownum, grp_start and slby columns and you want to output the group_no column, is that correct?

Comment: You do not appear to have a column that specifies the ordering of rows.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  `rownum` is a built-in Oracle pseudo-column, so it does not count.

Comment: it's only a simple analogy that different with the actual query, so just assume that the rownum is the PK.
noted: already answered by @Tejash and his explanation of what i need is better than me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your problem,

You are trying to calculate `GRP_NO` from `ROWNUM, GRP_STRT, GRP_NO, and SLBY`.

I have created the following query for you.

You can check the logic and apply it in your code accordingly:

```
SELECT
    RN,
    GRP_STRT,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN PREV_SLBY_DSTN_CD IS NULL
             OR PREV_SLBY_DSTN_CD <> SLBY_DSTN_CD THEN 1
    END) OVER(
    ORDER BY
        RN
    ) AS GRP_NO,
    SLBY_DSTN_CD   AS SLBY
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            RN,
            LAG(SLBY_DSTN_CD) OVER(
                ORDER BY
                    RN
            ) AS PREV_SLBY_DSTN_CD,
            SLBY_DSTN_CD,
            GRP_STRT
        FROM
            (SELECT ROWNUM RN, .... FROM SOME_TABLE) A
    )
```

This code is to generate the output as shown in question:

```
ROWNUM GRP_STRT GRP_NO SLBY
1      1        1      1
2      1        1      1
3      1        1      1
4      1        1      1
5      1        1      1
6      1        2      0
7      1        2      0
8      1        3      1
9      1        3      1
10     1        3      1
11     1        4      0
12     1        5      1
```

Cheers!!

Comment: whoaa nice! let me try it first, very nice understanding even though my explanation is the worst :D wait a moment...

Comment: excellent sir! Thank you so much! i'll try to apply it on my actual query.